# How to redirect to different url without changing url?

Tags: node.js

I have Domain A, and Domain B. Domains B is an alias/abbreviation for Domain A. I can use domain hosting provider to set this up. But is there a way to do it in nodejs.

So if user comes to Domain B then page that shows up is of Domain A. But url remains of Domain B.

And if possible there should be a way for all links in that site to point to Domain B (either using javascript or using server side templating if it's possible for server to know where did original request originated from).

I guess main question here is what 3xx header is to be used and how.

**Edit:** it doesn't have to be different domain, it can be different subdomain. or url like `domain.com/thisisbigurlthatmaycontainmoreurls/` vs `domain.com/tibutmcmu/`

Comment: This isn't possible, at least not from Node.js or by using 3xx redirects.

Comment: how come it's possible in php, mod_rewrite

Comment: Apache's mod_rewrite "tricks" PHP into thinking that some other URL was requested, and so PHP just renders the same content as it would have for the original URL.

Comment: You can define multiple routes `app.get('/a', renderA); app.get('/b', renderA)` that both do the same thing if that works for you..

Comment: Why not use an `iframe`?

Comment: take nginx with `proxy_pass` module - this will do the trick ;)